# Insert NA values in a data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I want an empty data frame and later add row values to it. The way I create a data frame is the following:

```
result_df <- data.frame("Hospital" = character(), "State" = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then I add the first row:

```
result_df <- rbind(result_df, list("D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "AL"))
```

Just as extra information I show you the result of the following command:

```
str(result_df)

'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X.D.W.MCMILLAN.MEMORIAL.HOSPITAL.: Factor w/ 1 level "D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL": 1
 $ X.AL.                            : Factor w/ 1 level "AL": 1
```

Then I add the next row to the data frame

```
result_df <- rbind(result_df, list("ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER", "TX"))
```

and this is what I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "TX") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

When I type result_df to see the content of the data frame this is the result:

```
  X.D.W.MCMILLAN.MEMORIAL.HOSPITAL. X.AL.
1    D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL
2                              <NA>  <NA>
```

I guess this could be solved using stringAsFactors = FALSE, does any one have an idea about this problem?

Comment: Don't use `rbind` in order to add rows. You should predefine the size of your `data.frame` and the use row indexes in order to populate it. In worst case scenario, you can easily add rows using indices, e.g., `result_df[1, ] <- c("D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "AL")` and `result_df[2, ] <- c("ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER", "TX")`. But then again, this will make a deep copy, instead, it is always better to predefine the seize of your data frame apriori.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rbind` function needs to have the same column names. If you created the data frame with the same column names, you can combine these data frames without NA.

```
result_df <- rbind(result_df, data.frame(Hospital = "D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
                                         state = "AL",
                                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

result_df <- rbind(result_df, data.frame(Hospital = "ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER", 
                                         state = "TX",
                                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Here is the final output.

```
print(result_df)
                           Hospital state
1    D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL
2 ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER    TX
```

Comment: Not sure the reason of the downvite. Please feel free to point out why this answer is insufficient.

Comment: I also got a dv for this.  Not sure though why it is dved

Comment: Great!!, Thank you so much!!, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(result_df, list("D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "AL")))
#                         Hospital State
#1: D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL
```